# scaffolder for Windows Azure and drupal

Tags: php, drupal, azure

I have setup all the things for Windows Azure and Drupal.

But, when I try to use 'scaffolder' command in 'c:\temp\', I get an error.

```
scaffolder is not internal or external command.
```

Does anybody know what this means?  Do you have any references on using Windows Azure and Drupal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the location for the scaffolder binary to your path environment variable? Its that or you have to navigate to its location and run from within that directory.

Comment: There are explicit instructions for setting up the SDK (including adding the scaffolder binary to your PATH environment variable, as Brent suggests) in this article: http://azurephp.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/setup-the-windows-azure-sdk-for-php

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.

Sorry, I did not add scaffolder binary path to my environment variable.

How can I do that? (I do not know the path of the scaffolder binary. I know how to add environment variables)

I will be thankful, if you give me the scaffolder binary path.

Regards,

Comment: Assuming you've takenthe defaults, you should find the Azure PHP SDK binaries (including the scaffolder utility) at "C:\Program Files\Windows Azure SDK for PHP\bin". More details can be found at: http://azurephp.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/setup-the-windows-azure-sdk-for-php#h2Section4

Answer (score 0):

As Brian said, there are detailed instructions at http://azurephp.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/setup-the-windows-azure-sdk-for-php

We are unable to tell you what your bin path is, but if you follow those instructions then it should be very easy to setup your PATH